# How to pre-populate HTML form fields with link in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have code for registration below. I want to pre-populate its form fields `name` and `position` from a link like `mydomain.com/register?ref=abc`.

```
<form class="form-signin" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post" name="form">
 {{csrf_field()}}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label for="fullname">Referrer Name</label>
<input class="form-styling" type="text" value="{{old('ref_name')}}" id="ref_name" required placeholder=""/>
<div id="ref">

</div>
@if ($errors->has('referrer_id'))
<span class="help-block">
 <strong>{{ $errors->first('referrer_id') }}</strong>
   </span>
   @endif
  </div>
```

I have tried :

```
app('request')->input('ref') in name fied
```

It pre-populates but validation of that pre-populated name does not occur.

validation code:

```
@if ($errors->has('referrer_id'))
<span class="help-block">
 <strong>{{ $errors->first('referrer_id') }}</strong>
   </span>
   @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

label must be assigned to input's id, validation to input's name.

```
<label for="fullname">Referrer Name</label>
<input class="form-styling" type="text" value="{{ old(request()->query('referrer_id')) }}" name="{{ request()->query('referrer_id') }}" id="fullname" required placeholder=""/>
```

and valitation

```
@if ($errors->has(request()->query('referrer_id')))
  <span class="help-block">
    <strong>{{ $errors->first(request()->query('referrer_id')) }}</strong>
  </span>
@endif
```

Comment: its not pre populate it

Comment: i updatet my answer. request()->query('ref ') should return ref value

Comment: yet not pre populating

Comment: i forgot to update error block. btw input name prepopulated on my machine

Comment: What laravel version? Be sure to type 'ref' parameter to url query

Comment: yes i am using whole code u provided. can we connnect via team viewer plz?

Comment: sorry i never used team viewer before

Comment: xapro.dev@gmail.com

Comment: thanks i am mailing you register and register controller

Comment: have you recieved?

Comment: hmm.. looks like you are using query 'referrer_id' not 'ref'?

Comment: i don't see mistakes in your code, i updated my answer. chek it pls

Comment: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\assets\core\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)"

Comment: this happens because you have no 'referrer_id' in query. I just tryied your full code. Works fine. But if you will not pass this attribute of course you will get this error. So url must be like this `mydomain.com/register?referrer_id=123`

Comment: ok thats right . but pre-populated field need a space key press for validation

Comment: Not sure what you mean. btw update your JS to use `#fullname` if you will use this id